# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'

Tags: linq

I want to define a function containing a Linq query as bellow:

```
public IQueryable GetBasket(Guid userId)
{
    DabbaghanDataContext db = new DabbaghanDataContext();

    int rowNo = 0;
    var query = (from c in db.Carts
                 join co in db.CartOrders on c.Id equals co.Cart_Id
                 join p in db.Products on co.Product_Id equals p.Id
                 where c.UserId == userId && c.Issued == false
                 select new
                 {
                     co.Quantity,
                     co.TotalPrice,
                     p.Code,
                     p.Price,
                     p.Thumbnail
                 }).AsEnumerable().Select(r => new
                 {
                     RowNumber = ++rowNo,
                     Quantity = r.Quantity,
                     TotalPrice = r.TotalPrice,
                     Code = r.Code,
                     Price = r.Price,
                     Thumbnail = r.Thumbnail
                 });

    return query;
}
```

I get error

> *Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'.*

on the `return query` line.

What is the problem? How can I solve this problem? Please help.

Comment: Why do you need the result as `IQueryable`?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the call to  `AsEnumerable`- It converts the `IQueryable` to a `IEnumerable`; and therefore, you cannot return it as an `IQueryable`.

Correct me if I am wrong, but the second select seems to only add the row number to the result. You might as well want to do that together with the initial select, and skip the call to `AsEnumerable()`.

Possible solutions: Rewrite the query to not use `AsEnumerable` (if you want an `IQueryable` returned), or you could change the return type to be `IEnumerable`, if that is a better fit for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In return query; change that to return query.AsQueryable();
And also try to change the method signature to use IQueryable instead of the nongeneric one